# ViewPager first fragment shown is always wrong with FragmentStatePager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am trying to have the same `view pager + tabs` design as the PlayStore 5.1.x. 
Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_tabs" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<FakeFragment> fragments;

    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        fragments = new ArrayList<FakeFragment>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        if(position < getCount()) {
            FakeFragment fragment = FakeFragment.newInstance(position);
            fragments.add(fragment);
        }
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Category.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Category.values()[position].getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

My tabs and pager are showing correctly ! but i have noticed that the first fragment shown in the view pager is always the same as the second one. Then when I swipe once, twice and swipe back to the first page, I find that the correct fragment is now shown !!

I can't understand why this behaviour, please I need some explanations.

**SOLUTION**

The issue was due to my `FakeFragment.newInstance()` method definition.

```
private static int position;

public static FakeFragment newInstance(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FakeFragment.position = position;
    return new FakeFragment();
}
```

I changed it by using a `setArguments(args)` to my `FakeFragment` instance, and then retrieve it in `onCreate` method. Now all is working nice !

Can somebody explain me why ??

I think that, in this way, value of position will entierly depend on fragment's lifecycle, so will be  always the expected position, Right ??

Comment: Get rid of `private ArrayList<FakeFragment> fragments` and just having `getItem()` return a new instance of the fragment. The **complete and entire *point*** behind `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is to **NOT** hold onto all of the fragments in memory. If that's what you want, then still get rid of the `ArrayList<FakeFragment>` and switch your adapter to be a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, rather than a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Also, get rid of `getItemPosition()`. [FWIW, here are a series of sample `ViewPager`-using apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. I chose the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` because I have 6 pages in my `ViewPager`, on each page I have a `GridView` with many data to show. Thats why I wanted to use this kind of adapter, to recreate a page or refresh it's content only if needed. That's why also I tried to override `getItemPosition`. Is this possible with `FragmentPagerAdapter` ? 
thanks again for replying !

Comment: Your implementation should work correctly in both cases, the only thing different may be the speed. If loading data is expensive and you don't need to do it everytime use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, use `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState` to store the loaded data set.

Comment: thanks @EugenPechanec, I will try to do what you suggested.

Comment: I solved the issue, but still don't understand it well. Please see my edit and help me understand this ! thanks in advance.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Eugen ... need your help one last time :)

Comment: I am having the same problem even today with very similar code. An array has [a, b , c ,d ] ..that should be the order of the pages. But my pages show up first time as [b, b, c, d]. On swiping backwards , c, b, a OR d, c, b ,a.   Logs show that the 1st adapter is getting Value a and position 0 but 'a' never gets displayed. Still wondering what could be wrong.

Comment: Please see my anaylsis and the way I figured out the problem stackoverflow.com/a/30968767/816635

Answer (score 6):

1) Do not implement `getItemPosition(Object)` if you don't handle it. You're not required to implement it and you might break some other functionality by implementing it wrong.

2) The point of `getItem(int)` is to return a new fragment. Ditch the fragment array as it makes no sense.

3) Make the adpater class `static` (It promotes reusability, the adapter should not depend on the parent class to get its data set, right?) and pass the `Category`s as a constructor parameter. Store it in a variable and make new fragments according to this data set. You'll also probably want to pass a `Category[position]` as a parameter to the fragment constructor instead of just `position`.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen, please can your give more information about the 3) : `the adapter should not depend on the parent class to get its data set` ?

Comment: It's best practice to declare nested classes `static`. This removes their implicit connection to their parent class (notice that you can't access the parent's field variables). In some cases this might prevent memory leaks. Only use non-static inner classes if you know what you're doing. Try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/70358/2444099).

Comment: I have accepted your answer and given you the bounties because your answer and comment led me to other usefull information.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your app.

Comment: please see the post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33012056/view-pager-first-and-second-fragment-data-is-not-updating-when-data-changed-in-a

Answer (score 3):

The `getItem()` implementation is the problem.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    return FakeFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

You should never alter the data in this get method: do not call `add()` in it. I doubt the `Adapter` would know at this point that you added an element.